# {"SyntaxException: Invalid input '{': expected an identifier character, whitespace

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

VB.NET program that loads a few thousand nodes and set up relationships between them. I'm using the Neo4J C# Client (version 1.1.0.8)

One of the commands is

```
TheConnection.GraphClient.Cypher.Match(
    "(user1:StartingPoint)",
    "(user2:Committee)"
).Where(
    Function(user1 As StartingPoint)
        user1.Id = KnowsID
).AndWhere(
    Function(user2 As Committee)
        user2.Id = KnownID
).Create(
    "user1-[r: Knows ]->user2"
).ExecuteWithoutResults()
```

For various business logic reasons I want to match the nodes by FECIDNumber (it's actually a string, in example 'C00530767') instead of ID. So I changed

1. KnownID from Long to String
2. user2.Id = KnownID

This gives me following query

```
TheConnection.GraphClient.Cypher.Match(
    "(user1:StartingPoint)",
    "(user2:Committee)"
).Where(
    Function(user1 As StartingPoint)
        user1.Id = KnowsID
).AndWhere(
    Function(user2 As Committee) user2.FECIDNumber = KnownID
).Create(
    "user1-[r: Knows ]->user2"
).ExecuteWithoutResults()
```

When executed it throws

```
{"SyntaxException: Invalid input '{':expected an identifier character, whitespace, '?', '!', '.', node labels, '[', ""=~"", IN, STARTS, ENDS, CONTAINS, IS, '^', '*', '/', '%', '+', '-', '=', ""<>"", ""!="", '<', '>', ""<="", "">="", AND, XOR, OR or ')' (line 3, column 23 (offset: 95))" & vbLf & """AND (user2.FECIDNumber{p1}{p2} = {p3})" & vbCr & """" & vbLf & "                       ^"}
```

When I go into the Neo4J Browser and run

```
MATCH (user:Committee) WHERE user.FECIDNumber = "C00530766" RETURN user
```

it returns the node as expected.

I think the important part of the error seems to be

```
(line 3, column 23 (offset: 95))
  " & vbLf & """AND (user2.FECIDNumber{p1}{p2} = {p3})" & vbCr & """" & vbLf & "
```

It looks like the Neo4J C# Client is tossing in a second parameter `{p2}`, but that's just a guess.

Any suggestions?

**Edit 1**

(I didn't know I could even pull the raw query text)

It's returning

```
MATCH (user1:StartingPoint), (user2:Committee)
WHERE (user1.Id = 1)
AND (user2.FECIDNumber"C00530766"false = 0)
CREATE user1-[r: Knows ]->user2
```

Clearly the problem is that

```
user2.FECIDNumber = KnownID).Create("user1-[r: Knows ]->user2")
```

is somehow generating

```
user2.FECIDNumber"C00530766"false = 0
```

Ideas? Is there a different syntax I should be using? Do I need to convert FECIDNumber to a different type?

**Edit 2**

The same code now generates

```
MATCH (user1:StartingPoint), (user2:Committee)
WHERE (user1.Id = 1)
AND (user2.FECIDNumber = "C00530766")
CREATE user1-[r: Knows ]->user2
```

And it creates the relationship as expected.

Winner.....

Comment: Can you get the debug query text from the query itself? I.e. Instead of executing it, save it to a variable, then look at .Query.DebugQueryText

Comment: Question is edited to include raw cypher query

Comment: I think it might be a symptom of the way VB handles string comparisons in lambda (a fix is here: https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/pull/93) I've not pulled in the pull request yet as I'm not 100% sure what needed to be changed to get it all to work, and there are no unit tests to confirm the fix works.

Comment: Would you be able to test a pre-release version if I upload one?

Comment: Sure. I'll have it installed and get the results back to you by 3PM EST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have published a version (1.1.0.26) which should resolve this for you, it'll take a few mins for Nuget to index it, so give it 1/2 an hour or so from when this is posted...

Let me know!